# How do I edit song metadata in Node using C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, module

I am trying to make a program in Node that automatically fills in metadata for a song (album,artist,name,etc.)

Is there a module out there that would let me do this? If not, how would I write one in C++?

Comment: What are you talking about? Do you mean that you want to set the MP3 tag data for a track in the file? Normally stuff like this gets called out to as an async process. That's what I would encourage you to do, figure out how to make this as an async call out to an external program that can do that for you using existing software.

Comment: If you don't find it using Google Web Search or Code Search, or the search on GitHub, then it's 99.9% that nobody have wrote this yet. As @jcolebrandφ suggests, just call an external program which handles this sort of manipulation on the type (or set of types) of files you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about ID3 tags, you can try Tim Smart's [node-id3](https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-id3). If you have npm installed just:

```
npm install id3
```

It seems written in JS using async calls.

Comment: I don't think this node module WRITES id3 tags to file, for what I've learned so far, it only have READ methods. @Eric, have you been able to do it?